# (VS2015) ReadFile on pipe failed The pipe has been ended

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using the VS2015 preview release and I can not get my solution to build due to the following build errors.

```
ReadFile on pipe failed The pipe has been ended.    SFD_Analyser    VBC 
could not find library '...\Projects\SFD\SFD_Analyser\bin\Debug\SFD_Analyser.dll'   VB_SFD  vbc 
Metadata file '...\Projects\SFD\SFD_Analyser\bin\Debug\SFD_Analyser.dll' could not be found VB_SFD.Vsix CSC 
Metadata file '...\Projects\SFD\VB_SFD\VB_SFD\bin\Debug\VB_SFD.dll' could not be found  VB_SFD.Vsix CSC
```

Extra information: Project Type: Diagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)
The code does not appear to have any errors.

**Fixed** 
My machine must have been in a strange state. As it builds successfully now.

Comment: @APerson The issue is something to due with the build system, not with the code. What that issue is I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** My machine must have been in a strange state. As it builds successfully now.